# How to disable the physical volume buttons on Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application, and my apps will play out an alarm once it is started, but I would like to disable the external volume buttons so that when the phone is alarming, user is not able to turn down the alarm volume. I have tested on my phone with Android version 2.3.5, but it is not working. Below is my coding. Hope someone can help me... Thanks.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: did you ever solved this?

Answer (score 12):

Try overriding `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    boolean result;
     switch( event.getKeyCode() ) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            result = true;
            break;

         default:
            result= super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            break;
     }

     return result;
}
```

also [see this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to play alarm sound on one audio stream ([AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_ALARM)) and make volume button to be associated with another audio stream ([`setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29)). http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#HardwareVolumeKeys

Answer (score 0):

just return true to disable volume operations.
and now you can do other operations from onVolumeDown() and onVolumeUp() functions.

```
 @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
          onVolumeDown();
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        onVolumeUp();

    return true;
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```